# background image is not working and path is correct

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to add an image as background below my header but it isn't showing.

My html is:

```
<body>
    <main>
        <section class="resumen" id="inicio">
            <h2>the imagen is supposed to be shown behind this text</h2>
        </section>
    <main>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
.resumen{
    height: 50vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(161, 140, 209, 0.5) 0%,
    rgba(251, 194, 235, 0.5) 100%, url(../images/fondo-inicio.jpg));
}
```

ROOT directory organization:

```
portfolioweb (main folder)
    - index.html
    -> files (folder)
        -> images (sub folder)
            -imagen.jpg (image that isn't showing)
        -> css (sub folder )
            -style.css
```

I have tried and none of them works

```
url(../images/fondo-inicio.jpg)
url('../images/fondo-inicio.jpg')
url(/images/fondo-inicio.jpg)
```

Comment: what is online url of this website ?

Comment: Is your image called 'fondo-inicio' like in the code, or 'imagen' like your file tree?

Comment: @AL.Sharie thanks bro. I forgot to close the ) after 100%, now it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't close `linear-gradient` in the right position

```
 background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(161, 140, 209, 0.5) 0%,
    rgba(251, 194, 235, 0.5) 100%, url(../images/fondo-inicio.jpg));
```

to

```
 background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(161, 140, 209, 0.5) 0%,
    rgba(251, 194, 235, 0.5) 100%), url(../images/fondo-inicio.jpg);
```

Answer (score -1):

try `url('./../files/images/fondo-inicio.jpg');`

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow.  As it says in the title of the question, the path isn't the problem here.  If you read the comments on the question, the OP realised they hadn't closed a quote.  You might find reviewing [this guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) to be helpful, and please use backticks to format inline code samples - it makes it easier to identify them as such.